# svn diff: file marked as binary type

Tags: svn, file-type

I'm doing an `svn diff` on one of my files and svn is detecting it as a binary type. The file is readable plain text and I would like to be able to get a diff of this file. How do I tell SVN that this is not a binary file?

```
Cannot display: file marked as a binary type.
svn:mime-type = application/octet-stream
```

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can use the [Subversion property](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.properties.html) svn:mime-type to set an explicit mimetype on the file:

```
svn propset svn:mime-type 'text/plain' path/to/file
```

Alternatively, you can delete this property (since Subversion assumes plaintext, otherwise) using:

```
svn propdel svn:mime-type path/to/file
```

Comment: But why was it marked as binary in the first place? I am having the same issue for many of my source files, and it is a pain to delete the properties every time.

Comment: Sounds like you should ask another question ... and maybe add a link here.

Comment: @EricWilson -- asked:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499334/svn-diff-why-are-some-files-marked-as-binary

Comment: Does this (changing the mime type of a file) change the way files are executed when someone checks out a fresh copy from svn? In such a case I think using --force option just for viewing the diff makes more sense.

Comment: @Rishi, no, it doesn't; there is a separate "svn:executable" property which determines whether the file should have executable permission bits.

Answer (score 120):

You can get diff even for a file marked as binary by using `--force`.

`svn diff --force path/to/file`

Comment: this is a much better answer for something like application/json

Comment: @BrettZamir but that could be done with almost anything that has an output.

Comment: @entonio : Yes, I know...just thought I should point it out as I ran into this error using a GUI client and as I could not resolve within it as far as I could tell, thought maybe others who do not frequently use the command line could be informed of this.