# Persistently overriding svn's mime to binary mapping?

Tags: svn, mime-types

For background on my question: svn won't diff a file it thinks is binary

```
$ svn diff data/assets/site/ir_gallery/images.kml
Index: data/assets/site/ir_gallery/images.kml
===================================================================
Cannot display: file marked as a binary type.
svn:mime-type = application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml
```

A recent stack overflow answer ( [svn diff: file marked as binary type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634043/svn-diff-file-marked-as-binary-type) ) showed you can force a mime type:

```
$ svn propset svn:mime-type 'text/plain' data/assets/site/ir_gallery/images.kml
property 'svn:mime-type' set on 'data/assets/site/ir_gallery/images.kml'
```

Note that prior answer is incomplete... you also have to:

```
$ svn commit
```

---

Now my *new* question is: can I set a default, so all future "vnd.google-earth.kml+xml" files are treated as text by svn?   The redbook appears silent on this topic: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.2/svn.advanced.props.html saying only:

```
...if a file's svn:mime-type property is set to a non-text MIME type
(generally, something that doesn't begin with text/, though there are
exceptions) then...
```

What exceptions? Are these exceptions baked into the svn code, or accessible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer depends on the svn client that you are using.  In the official svn client, the option you are looking for is [Automatic Property Setting](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.props.html#svn.advanced.props.auto).  The tl;dr version is you need to update your [user or system config](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.confarea.html#svn.advanced.confarea.opts.config), set the `enable-auto-props` setting to `yes` in the `miscellany` section, and create a new section called `auto-props` which defines the patterns you want to match and the properties you are looking to set.

For your example of kml files:

```
### Section for configuring miscelleneous Subversion options.
[miscellany]
enable-auto-props = yes

[auto-props]
*.kml = svn:mime-type=text/plain;svn:eol-style=native
```

This will ensure that when you add a .kml file to your repository, it will have a mime-type of text/plain and will use line endings native to the platform of the client.

Comment: he may prefer `*.xml = svn:mime-type=text/xml` because kml is an xml IIRC

Comment: By the way, the svn:mime-type=text/...; part is critical, because if it is not there, there is an initial-property-set that sets it to non-text, application/xml, which would cause the svn:eol-style=native to error-out, preventing the whole file-add step. The mime-type=text/... overrides the binary nature of the file first such that the eol-style-native can be set.